# Yii - What is the benefit to a filter if it is only for a single action?

Tags: php, yii

I am working my way through a Yii tutorial book and am currently learning about filters.  Filters can be applied in general for the controller or just to specific actions.

The example I am working on is creating a new Issue.  Each Issue belongs to a single Project, so we add a filter to ensure the `project_id` is passed to the `issue/create` page.  Since the `issue/create` is the only page that needs the `project_id`, we are applying the filter to a single action:

```
public function filters(){
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'projectContext + create',//check to ensure valid project context
    );
}
```

My question is this: If a filter only applies to a single action in the controller, why not just put the `filterProjectContext()` code directly into the `actionCreate()` function?

Comment: The example you are working on is a bit contrived, so not a good illustration of how a filter might be used. Just look at it as a tutorial for the mechanics, and keep an open mind as regards to how you would actually use filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the [yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter), and my experience with other frameworks, filters are not meant to be coupled with actions. Rather, filters allow you the ability to access PHP globals such as `$_REQUEST` values before they reach any actions. For example, I worked on a project where we wanted to highlight all translated text if a url parameter was passed with a specific value. We could have done this in the controller but felt it was better to implement the business rule within a filter. The filter ended up looking like:

```
// Symfony code, but should demonstrate the idea
if ($context->getRequest()->getParameter('highlightTranslations') === 'y') {
    // Tell translator API to highlight any subsequent translations
}
```

The beauty of the filter is that this code would be executed regardless of which action was requested. My suggestion is that you don't co-mingle filter logic with action logic.

Comment: Even action-specific filters can be handy to rely on write-once functionality that ends up being configuration-driven per-use-case.  An excellent example is caching with COutputCache.  An action-specific filter lets you perform fine-grained configuration of cache duration/factors, and the logic of pre-empting the action+handling the cache becomes hands-free (i.e. you don't have to maintain it) while your action logic remains simple and clear.  As a rule of thumb, if I'm implementing functionality that CAN be de-coupled from the action it supports and could ever be userful in another, I do so.